# Sequelize - Matching all records of a given entity in mySQL database

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have three MySQL (v8) tables

TABLE 1:

```
students (contains details of all students)
- id
- full_name
- email
```

Records:

```
| id | full_name | email             |
|----|-----------|-------------------|
| 1  | John      | john@example.com  |
| 2  | Adam      | adam@example.com  |
| 3  | James     | james@example.com |
| 4  | Jane      | jane@example.com  |
```

TABLE 2:

```
courses (contains all courses)
- id
- title
```

Records:

```
| id | title  |
|----|--------|
| 1  | PHP    |
| 2  | Python |
| 3  | .Net   |
| 4  | HTML   |
```

TABLE 3:

```
student_courses (this table contains which student has subscribed to what courses)
- student_id
- course_id
```

Records:

```
| id | student_id | course_id |
|----|------------|-----------|
| 1  | 1          | 1         |
| 2  | 1          | 2         |
| 3  | 2          | 3         |
| 4  | 3          | 1         |
```

The problem I am facing here is I need to get a list of all students who have opted for both course ids 1 & 2, which in the above example is "John".

Using sequelize I have tried the following two where clauses, but both giving me incorrect results.

Option 1) This is giving me empty result set

```
where: {
    course_id: {
        [Op.and]: [1,2]
    }
}
```

Option 2) This is returning "John" as well as "James". It shouldn't return "James" since he has subscribed to only course id 1.

```
where: {
    course_id: [1, 2]
}
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: in non-sequelize terms, you need to inner join on student_courses twice, once for with a course_id=1 and the second one with a course_id=2.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve N:M associations by using this, More information can be found here http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-belongsToMany

```
//add required associations

students.associate = (models) => {
    students.belongsToMany(models.courses, {
      through: 'student_courses',
      foreignKey: 'student_id'
    });
};

// now query the db like this
db.students.findAll({
   where: { full_name : 'john'},
   include: [{
      model: db.courses,
      where: {
          id: {
             [Op.and]: [1,2]
                }
          }
    }]
})
```

Comment: Why have you mentioned `{ full_name : 'john'}` in where clause? the where clause should contain the course ids i.e. 1 & 2 which should return details of "John" since he is the only one who has subscribed to both courses 1 & 2

Comment: you can update it according to your required condition.

Comment: I have updated the code according to your condition.

Comment: Great!, I shall try this out and get back if I face any issue. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Update: Tried your solution, its giving me empty array result.